# How not to break phrase into word when do faceting

Tags: solr, faceted-search

All:

Im pretty new to Solr faceting search, when I specify some facet fields which have phrase as value, how can I just treat the value as a whole phrase but not word and only return one facet. For example:

If I have documents with field like:
{ "category": "baby toy"}, {"category": "clothes"}

And the result returned will look like:

["baby", 0, "boy", 0, "clothes", 1]

I wonder why it works like this and how to change it to what I mentioned above, like:

["baby boy", 1, "clothes", 1]

Thanks

Comment: Most people will want to know your analysis on the field? It's probably not string. Are you using standard or whitespace tokenizer? I think you need KeywordTokenizer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer on that field. (I'm not sure whether this would work) Or change it to string, but this will make you lose many analysis options

Comment: @DavidVdd thanks. I will reindex that field as string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field you use for faceting should be defined in schema.xml as a string (type="string") in order for the facet to use the whole text. Otherwise it will divide it according to the way it has been tokenized.

Answer (score 1):

The faceting field should be indexed as whole. So in your schema.xml check how you are token-zing this field.
you should use Keyword Tokenizer that index entire text field as a single token.

Ref https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer